# findAll method its been returning an empty list

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

i am learning web scraping, so i'am trying to scrape a website https://nl.indeed.com/jobs?q=python+developer&l=Amsterdam&vjk=b073fb1938c41557 but python find_all() method returns empty lists, i have tried html.parser coz thats the only parser i know how to use. the classes i'm trying to scrape are present in the source code as well as in the soup object but things aren't seem to be working, any help will be appreciated.
thanks

i tried this code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://nl.indeed.com/jobs?q=python+developer&l=Amsterdam&vjk=b073fb1938c41557"
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(`your text`page.content, 'html.parser')
results = soup.find_all('div', class_="cardOutline tapItem fs-unmask result")
print(results)
```

i was expecting it to print the classes, i then changed the results to

```
results = soup.find_all('div', {"class":"cardOutline tapItem fs-unmask result"})
```

but still the same thing happens it returns an empty list again.

Comment: The site is filled with JavaScript. BS4 won't be able to parse this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Web-scraping JavaScript page with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049520/web-scraping-javascript-page-with-python)

Answer (score 0):

The website as explained in comments is generated by `javascript`. So you need another lib.

Try this valid [css](/questions/tagged/css) selector with [dryscrape](/questions/tagged/dryscrape) [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) aware Python lib:

```
div.cardOutline.tapItem.fs-unmask.result
```

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

url = "https://nl.indeed.com/jobs?q=python+developer&l=Amsterdam&vjk=b073fb1938c41557"
import dryscrape
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
session = dryscrape.Session()
session.visit(url)
response = session.body()
soup = BeautifulSoup(response, "html.parser")
results = soup.select('div.cardOutline.tapItem.fs-unmask.result')
print(results)
```

Comment: 1) Question is about [tag:bs4], not [tag:dryscrape]. 2) 9/10 questions about [tag:bs4] are due to [tag:js] generated content. There is a [perfect duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049520/web-scraping-javascript-page-with-python) for that, that also includes a [tag:dryscrape] alternative. So don't see why this answer helps.

Comment: Hummm, the code is specific to OP needs, don't you see the value here???

Comment: Yea, I see, but why wouldn't this be a duplicate on the question that I've linked? Something I'm missing that not mentioned in the dupe?

Comment: My answer give not only recommendations but **code**

Comment: Which is also in the marked duplicate, without the url and selector, but guessing OP can copy/paste those as well.

Comment: I don't agree. His CSS selector was wrong

Comment: Yea oke, so leave a comment about the wrong CSS selector and vote to close as dupe so that OP can read about *why* bs4 won't work out-of-the-box due to the JS generated content, something you're not explaining. (since the css selector isn't the main cause of the empty result). The marked dupe does provide that info, with the same snippet. I'm sorry, thought this was the way to go, nothing to do with you personally.